# Managing GET and POST at the same action on Rails 4 problems

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have this in my routes file:

```
match "/register/:invitation_code", to: "users/invites#register", as: "register_by_invite", via: [:get, :post]
```

I have the following controller structure:

- users/invites_controller.rb

And this is my controller's code:

```
class Users::InvitesController < ApplicationController

  def GET_register
    @invite = Invite.find_by_invite_code(params[:invitation_code])
  end

  def POST_register
  end

end
```

My view structure:

- views/users/invites/register.html.erb

For some reason, all the instances (@invite...) are not being sent to the view, that's really weird and I'm stuck with this the whole day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't just name your controller actions like that.

At the moment, both your GET and POST requests are trying to render the `register` action (and your `GET_register` and `POST_register` ones are being completely ignored). You don't need a controller action so it's not using one, it's just rendering the view `register.html.erb`.

If you want to use two different actions for the same URL (with different HTTP methods), you need two different routes. One for the GET route, one for the POST route. `edit` and `update` would be the normal action names you would use for this - because it's what you're doing, updating an Invite object.

Comment: I'm feeling so dumb right now... it worked! I can only accept your answer in 9 minutes though. Thanks!